# Get variables from txt file and run them into loop with BATCH

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file, for-loop

I need to assign variables form txt file.

1.txt

```
Extinct
Legends
```

And I want to use them in for loop with this command.

```
C:\another.bat "%var%"
```

Which means when I run the bat file It will do C:\another.bat "Extinct" and after that C:\another.bat "Legends".

How to do that?

Comment: the second line only? Or every line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
set "file_loc=1.txt"
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%L in ("%file_loc%") do (

  call   C:\another.bat "%%~L" 

)
```